# Sum multidimensional associative array values while preserving key names

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

There are many [nice Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286749/array-sum-of-value-based-on-same-key) on Stackoverflow on how to take a multidimensional associative array and sum values in it. Unfortunately, I can't find one where the key names **aren't** lost.

For example:

```
$arr=array(
      array('id'=>'1', 'amount'=>'5'),
      array('id'=>'1', 'amount'=>'5'),
      array('id'=>'2', 'amount'=>'1'),
      array('id'=>'2', 'amount'=>'3')
);
```

I want the resulting array to look like this:

```
$result=array(
  array('id'=>'1', 'amount'=>'10'),
  array('id'=>'2', 'amount'=>'4')
);
```

Unfortunately the only thing I can figure out how to do is this:

```
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $amount){
  if(!array_key_exists($amount['id'], $arr))          
  $result[$amount['id']] =0; 
  $result[$amount['id']] += $amount['amount'];
}
```

Which when `echo'd` as follows produces (notice the lack of the keys' words "id" and "amount"):

```
foreach($result as $id => $amount){
  echo $id."==>".$amount."\n";
}

1==>10
2==>4
```

Comment: The key names exist, you are just aren't outputting them. At least, they should if you ran the code you showed.

Comment: @crush thanks, so I don't need what Colin suggests below? I'm a little confused still, can you fiddle a bit? ==> http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: @timpeterson The keys are not there in your resulting array. Not sure what crush is referring to. May I ask what you need the array in this structure for anyway?

Comment: The keys are there. They just aren't in the dimension you are iterating through.

Comment: @ColinMorelli, i need to ultimately produce a json object so  `$results` needs to be an associative array so I can `json_encode` it. Is there something specific you're trying to tell me?

Comment: @crush can you provide code?

Comment: @crush You're talking about a technicality given the fact that the OP is using the `$arr` array for the source data and resulting data - which I doubt would really be the case. Using the summing method the OP is describing would not yield the array keys in the result. It would only give the ID as the array key, and the sum as its value. Tim, I'd advise you just use my suggestion.

Comment: @ColinMorelli yeah that was a mistake (now corrected), thanks, i'll use your answer...

Comment: @timpeterson Looks like you changed the code you originally posted. Cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use that method, and then reconstruct the array you want at the end?

```
$results = array();
foreach ($arr as $id=>$amount) {
    $results[] = array('id' => $id, 'amount' => $amount);
}
```

Any other way of doing this would be more computationally expensive.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired result at all.

Comment: As the answer indicates, this method does not sum the items, because the original question already does that. It simply re-constructs the array to get it back into the format the OP asked for. It certainly does produce the desired result, if - as the answer states - using the method the OP already started with.

Comment: See https://d26dzxoao6i3hh.cloudfront.net/items/1H472z3c1D3U071g3V3W/Screen%20Shot%202017-08-10%20at%2015.13.23.png.

Comment: I have no idea what I'm looking at. Given an associative array of `id => value`, this method most certainly reconstructs the array the OP asked for. Once again, this answer does nothing with summing results because the OP has _already_ done that.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show that you **already** had the data you originally needed, though, the answer you accepted is a better way to deal with it.

You have the following to start with right?

```
$arr = array(
    array('id'=>'1', 'amount'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'1', 'amount'=>'5'),
    array('id'=>'2', 'amount'=>'1'),
    array('id'=>'2', 'amount'=>'3')
);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [amount] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [amount] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [amount] => 3
        )
)
```

Then you run it through the following algorithm:

```
$summedArr = array();

foreach ($arr as $amount) {
    $summedArr['amount'][$amount['id']] += $amount['amount'];
    $summedArr['id'][$amount['id']] = $amount['id'];
}
```

Now, disregarding the `Notice` warnings that are produced since you are referencing indexes that don't yet exist, this outputs the following:

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [amount] => Array
        (
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 4
        )
    [id] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
)
```

Do you see the keys, yet? Because I do.

Now iterate over the array:

```
foreach ($summedArr as $key => $value) {
    echo $k . "==>" . $v . "\n";
}
```

**Output**

```
amount==>Array
id==>Array
```

That's not what you want, though. You want:

```
foreach ($summedArr as $key => $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $v) {
        echo $key . "==>" . $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP removed that code and changed it out for a different counting algorithm. And either way, despite the keys being there, they're still not in the format the OP needs them in. You'll see he was using them for `json_encode`ing the results back to a browser - so either way the arrays will have to be reconstructed per my suggestion

Comment: Sure they are. He simply wasn't referencing them right. I just now saw the that he switching the code out later. I was obviously referencing the original code. You can stop with your snarky comments. I'm not trying to steal your accepted answer kid. Notice how I endorse it at the beginning of mine.

Comment: Not about the accepted answer, it's about getting the right solution. Go ahead and `json_encode` your result so that the OP can access them in javascript like this: `results[0].id` and `results[0].amount` without reconstructing arrays. Apologize if I came off rude - wasn't the intention. I just don't believe this is what the OP needs

Comment: Who said anything about not reconstructing arrays? The OP was echoing plain strings originally, not encoding JSON. Get over yourself. Yes, he would have to reconstruct the array. That is obvious.

Comment: @crush sorry about this. I didn't see my mistakes. Colin's answer works for me but I upvoted your answer b/c I appreciate your effort. I just need some more minutes to make sense of it...

Comment: @crush My intention isn't to be rude - but the OP stated he needs to `json_encode` it in one of the comments. Simple miscommunication. Between all 3 of us. In either case - the solution has been found.

Comment: @ColinMorelli You are being quite rude and obtuse. It's like you are threatened or something. If you had read the OP's original example, you would have seen that he was confused why his echo statements weren't producing what he wanted in his json_encode. I addressed that by showing him why it wasn't in the structure he expected, and showing him that the data did actually exist a level up. In the future, this will allow the OP to debug his own code, and produce the proper structure.

Comment: @crush Alright - you can argue with my apology. I gave it a shot. Good work on your answer. Thanks.