# Group row data of a 2d array by one column and sum another column within each group to create a flat, associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I want to sum up the given quantities (`qty`) After grouping by the first two columns in each row.  I'd like an associative result like this:

```
[
    'blyszczaca Normal' => 6,
    'czapkoszal Normal' => 6,
    'czapkoszal Luxury' => 2,
    'etola Wolf' => 1,
    'etola Normal' => 2,
]
```

My input array:

```
[
    ['produkt' => 'blyszczaca', 'model' => 'Normal', 'price' => 27.00, 'qty' => 2],
    ['blyszczaca', 'Normal', 27.00, 2],
    ['blyszczaca', 'Normal', 27.00, 2],
    ['czapkoszal', 'Normal', 41.00, 2],
    ['czapkoszal', 'Luxury', 45.00, 2],
    ['czapkoszal', 'Normal', 41.00, 2],
    ['czapkoszal', 'Normal', 41.00, 1],
    ['czapkoszal', 'Normal', 41.00, 1],
    ['etola', 'Wolf', 47.00, 1],
    ['etola', 'Normal', 39.00, 1],
    ['etola', 'Normal', 39.00, 1],
]
```

Comment: Related: [Group array data on one column and sum data from another column to form a flat associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3286749/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create new array with unique keys and count quantities, for example:

```
$sums = [];
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    // create a unique key as concatenation of `product` and `model`
    $key = $item['product'] . ':' . $item['model'];

    // check if such key exists, if not - init key with `0`
    if (!isset($sums[$key])) {
        $sums[$key] = 0;
    }

    // add current `qty` to the value of `$sums[$key]`
    $sums[$key] += $item['qty']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom key based on `produkt` and `model` in your output array. Then, add `qty` to that key. Try the following:

```
// Create a array to store the sum
$sums = array();

// Loop over the input array 
foreach ($input as $value) {

    // create a custom key based on produkt and model
    $key = $value['produkt'] . ' ' . $value['model'];

    // initalize the key 
    $sums[$key] = $sums[$key] ?? 0;

    // add the quantity
    $sums[$key] += (int)$value['qty'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your input array has inconsistent keys, use `array_values()` to re-index rows before trying to access their data.

Form the identifying composite value as a space-delimited string containing the first and second element of each row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eG6G8))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $row = array_values($row);
    $group = "$row[0] $row[1]";
    $result[$group] = ($result[$group] ?? 0) + $row[3];
}
var_export($result);
```